# new-hist - Got an exception: Could not open log file ... check access rights

Tags: horizon

When I try to create a new-hist I get the following error. Does anyone has an idea how I can fix this? TY

```
 sudo -u stellar stellar-core --conf /etc/stellar/stellar-core.cfg new-hist local3
2021-11-04T16:48:37.818 [default INFO] Config from /etc/stellar/stellar-core.cfg
2021-11-04T16:48:37.819 [default INFO] Generated QUORUM_SET: {
   "t" : 2,
   "v" : [ "core-validator-3", "core-validator-2", "core-validator-1" ]
}
2021-11-04T16:48:37.819 [default INFO] Assigning calculated value of 1 to FAILURE_SAFETY
2021-11-04T16:48:37.820 GD3NX [default FATAL] Got an exception: Could not open log file stellar-core-2021-11-04_16-48-37.log, check access rights
2021-11-04T16:48:37.820 GD3NX [default FATAL] Please report this bug along with this log file if this was not expected
```